# How to use ImageOptim with asset catalogs on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, png, asset-catalog, image-optimization

For PNGs not contained in an asset catalog Xcode's supposedly inferior optimization can be disabled through the `COMPRESS_PNG_FILES` settings. However, this doesn't seem to affect PNGs inside asset catalogs (see [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7263918?start=0&tstart=0) question and answer). Does anyone know of a way to disable the builtin optimization on asset catalogs in favor of [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac) or something similar?